Why is my wifi not working on my Lenovo ideaPad 1
so today I bought a Lenovo IdeaPad 1 15IAU7. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and it didn't even give me an option for connecting to wifi nor do I have any symbols to connect to wifi. I don't even have an Ethernet port to connect hard wired. I used the terminal with the following command to see my built in wifi card. sudo lshw -class network. The results is
Network: unclaimed 
Description: network controller
Product: realtek semiconductor Co., Ltd.
Physical id: 0
Bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
Version: 00
Width: 64 bits
Clock: 33mhz
Capabilities: pm MSI pciexpress cap_list
Configuration: latency=0
Resources: import:3000(size=256) memory:50500000-505fffff

Since my laptop has no way to connect online how can I turn on my wifi card manually on the command line?
